# Firebase Rules Everyone reads and no one can write

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a news application connected with Firebase and I add the news manually in Firestore only, inside 5 Collection, I am not good at using Firebase, I use the test mode and now I need your help in changing it, the application is for news, meaning no one can add in it only read the data from  Everyone without even logging in, I get many security messages from Google, please write me the code here because I browsed a lot of questions here and I didn't understand anything and it seems that I need a course on Firebase security.

I use a pay-per-use plan, and I'm afraid of high bills. Please help me with a strong security that protects me from fake reading or even writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer without an understanding of your firestore collection names but here is a general solution.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
   // in this example, only admins can write or delete, but anyone can read.
    match /news/{docId}{
      allow read;
      allow write, delete: if isAdmin(request);
     }

   // This is an example for a users collection, where the doc ID is the 
   // users authentication Id
   // Note the userId=** -> this will apply rules to all subcollections
   match /users/{userId=**}{
    allow read: if isAuthenticated(request); // logged in users can read

    // Only admins or the user with a matching doc Id can write.
    allow write: if isAdmin(request) || isOwner(userId); 

    allow delete: if isAdmin(request); // only admins can delete
   }


    function isOwner(userID){
        return request.auth.uid == userID;
    }

    function isAuthenticated(request){
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    // this requires you to have set up custom claims
    function isAdmin(request) {
     return request.auth.token.admin
    }
    
  }
}
```

To learn more about protecting your collections with role based authentication, take a look at [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)